# Clojure REPL not printing prior to asking for input

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a generic function that asks for input from the user, validates it via a passed function, and displays a message if the input is bad.

The problem I'm facing is the message asking for input doesn't actually print until *after* the user has already given the input.

Since I'm using `print` instead of `println`, stream buffering is the obvious culprit, but even after flushing after printing, it still doesn't print at the right time. Here's the simplest example of the problem:

```
(defn- fprint [message]
  (print message)
  (flush))

(defn simple-interact []
  (fprint "123")
  (fprint (read-line))
  (fprint "456"))
```

Using IntelliJ IDEA's REPL, running this causes a popup input prompt. If I enter `abc` into the prompt, it prints `123abc456` *at once* instead of in parts; `123` isn't printed until *after* I've already given the input.

I'm using `print` instead of `println` because the real function I'm writing displays a given message, and I don't want to force it to print a newline if the intial message is intended to be a prompt. For reference, here's the full function and helpers:

```
(defn- print-mesage? [message]
  (and message (not= message "")))

(defn- fprint [message]
  (print message)
  (flush))

(defn- fprint? [message]
  (if (print-mesage? message)
    (fprint message)))

(defn restricted-ask-for-input
  "Asks a user for input. Will repeatedly ask until their input is verified via validate-f.
  The ask message is displayed once before input is first asked for.
  The error message is displayed every time validation fails.
  If either of the messages is empty, or falsey, they won't be printed.
  The messages dont' have a newline added after them."
  [ask-message error-message validate-f]
  (fprint? ask-message)
  (loop []
      (let [in (read-line)]
        (if (validate-f in)
          in
          (do
            (fprint? error-message)
            (recur))))))
```

I really need to be able to print prior to asking for input so the user knows what's being asked.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Just as a test after posting this I tried changing `fprint` to use `println` instead, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Try running it on the command line via "lein run", and I think you'll see the behavior you expect.

Comment: @AlanThompson So you think this is a REPL issue?

Comment: @AlanThompson Yep, you're right. From the command line, it works fine. I was able to "interact" with the REPL not too long ago, now all of a sudden `(get-line)` causes a popup prompt to be displayed, and this behavior started happening. They must have broke something.